# Can not find php session setup file mod_files.sh on Fedora 23

Tags: php, apache, session, fedora

I going thru the php manual and looking the session section and it states to use a file located at ext/session named mod_files.sh to setup session directories but I am not find a ext/session dir and the file.

Doc link:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Using php 5.6 with Apache.

Thanks.

Comment: `find / -type f -name mod_files.sh -print`

Comment: @Pamblam, Thank you, comes back right away with just:
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied

I did run with sudo, so thinking file does exist?